# FileSystemWatcher: how to know which process made the change?

Tags: vb.net, process, filesystemwatcher

is it possible to get the name of the process that caused the change in the filesystem?

i want to do this programmatically [ie, i can't use any external 3rd party tools like handle]

any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OS doesn't provide such information. You would need a file system filter driver for fine-grain control over changes made on the file system.

Comment: If you are interested only in specific files, you can create a "write" security audit for those files. Then the information will be recorded in the event log.

Comment: @Raymond this should be either an "independent" answer or a comment to original question.