# How can I monitor file attribute changes in Windows?

Tags: delphi, attributes, monitor

Apologies if this is the wrong forum but I know there are a lot of talented people here.

I have a folder in C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local containing a few xml files. Something is occasionally changing the attributes of these files and making them read only.

I know there are many utilities to monitor **when** attributes change and **what** they change to etc. but is there a way to monitor **which program or process** made the change?

If I need to code something then I'm competent in using Delphi 2009

Comment: You can find the answer here e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/6615999/8041231.

Comment: Yes, I had already looked at that. It suggested I need "a file system filter driver for fine-grain control over changes made on the file system" But I have no idea what one of those is. It also suggests creating "a "write" security audit" which I did but that was not able to tell me which process accessed the file, only which user.

Comment: This is a commercial option: https://www.eldos.com/cbflt/filesystem-filter-driver-sdk.php

Comment: [SysInternals Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor) tells you which processes touch which files and how.

Comment: Ah, I have that, thank you Remy. Looking at http://answers.perforce.com/articles/KB/3035 I found out how to use it to watch a particular file and that has answered my question.  -    How do I mark your reply as being accepted when it was just a comment?